# Error:createClient is not defined When using supabase cdn

Tags: cdn, supabase

I'm using [Supabase](https://supabase.com/) CDN's for a project. When I call the `createClient()` function this error comes up:

```
createClient is not defined
```

I tried it with an older version of the CDN, with another browser and using the old method of `SupabaseClient.createClient`, but I got:

```
SupabaseClient is not defined
```

Is the CDN not working correctly or something else?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>HTML</title>

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p>Nothing to see here...</p>

  <!-- Project -->

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js@2"></script>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const SupabaseKey = // api here
const SupabaseUrl =// URL here

const options = {
  db: {
    schema: 'public',
  },
  auth: {
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: true
  }
}

const supabase = createClient(SupabaseUrl, SupabaseKey, options)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by adding an import statement in the JS file like this:

```js
import createClient from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js/+esm'
```

The +esm at the end of the URL is from universal module and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain  tags to import supabase-js from CDNs, like:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js@2"></script>
```

or even:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@supabase/supabase-js@2"></script>
```

Then you can use it from a global supabase variable:

```
<script>
  const { createClient } = supabase
  const _supabase = createClient('https://xyzcompany.supabase.co', 'public-anon-key')

  console.log('Supabase Instance: ', _supabase)
  // ...
</script>
```

the esm way mentioned above did not work for me so i did a bit of research and found out about this one on the [jsdelivr page.](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@supabase/supabase-js)

from what i understand the method of importing like that only works if you install the package in npm or deno.